# React-router links don't work when accessed directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got a simple React app with react-router that fetches data (say, a list of countries) in its App component which is then mapped to links.

The routing logic is in the App component. There are two routes: the base link (`'/'`, shows a base page) and the `'/:id'` link (shows pages based on data fetched with `useEffect` and then mapped to components). Everything works fine when following links through the app (i.e. `'/' -> '/Mexico'`. But when I try to access parametrized link directly, the data seems to be not set at all.

I believe the problem is in the `useEffect`, for some reason it doesn't seem to fetch data unless starting from the `'/'`. I might be wrong, but for now I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample code:

```
const App = () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/data'
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useeffect in use');
    (async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(url)
      setData(res.data)
    })()
  }, [])

  const match = useRouteMatch('/:id')
  const country = match 
    ? data.find(x => x.country === match.params.id)
    : null

  return(
    <div className='container'>
      <Search data={data} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/:id'>
          <Country country={country} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/'>
          <div>Base</div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It would be great if some sample code could be given.

Comment: @NanoBit updated my question with the code of the App

Comment: Do you get an empty page ? or your `App` but without the `Country` component ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I get an error originating from the Country component. The argument (a data bit) provided for it is undefined, which made me check the data fetched in the App component and it is an empty array (initial state)

Comment: it is undefined because the data have not been fetched yet. You will need to guard agains such a case but returning null or some loading message from your `Country` if the `country` prop is not set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with this piece of code:

```
const country = match 
  ? data.find(x => x.country === match.params.id)
  : null
```

When you enter your main path `'/'` you make a call to the api in `useEffect`. Next, you get an answer and call `setData`. You have some data in the array and you can succesffully call a `data.find` method.
But when you enter to the parametrized link directly, `data.find` will return `undefined`, because your data is an empty array. Make sure that you will fetch data before matching the url parameter.

Comment: It seems that you're correct. But how do I achieve that? I tried something like ```const countrySetter = async () => {
    await data
    return match 
    ? data.find(x => x.country === match.params.id)
    : null
  }``` and then ```<Country country={countrySetter()} />```and the page loads, the data is set but the argument a promise thus I'm having a hard time getting its contents

Comment: I would just change your code to `const country = match && data.length > 0 ? data.find(x => x.country === match.params.id) : null`. SetState will rerender component and your match should be correct. I think, for the future, you should make some protection in `Country` component, just to be sure it will render even, if you don't have correct data.

Comment: tried your suggestion but the problem still persists @qve1t

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that I've got it solved it seems too easy. But I've just inserted the following block of code into the `App` component:

```
if (data.length < 1) {
  return(
    <div>Loading data...</div>
  )
}
```

Thanks all for your input!